# allow remove call from list interface, but not remove item from implementation

Tags: java, database, list

I created a list implementation to wrap calls to a database and cache the return objects. With this implementation, you can iterate over the list and perform most operations on the list, and the implementation will go to the database when needed to get the items requested. However i am struggling to figure out how i can implement the remove method. I can't actually remove the element from the database. However if a user removed element 0, when they call get(0) afterwards, my implementation needs to return element 1. Does anyone have experience in this area and could help me out with this?

Comment: Why don't you post whatever you have done so far ?

Comment: You could probably have some "buffer" `List` internally to your implementation, to cache invocations after initial population with DB values. Your question not specific enough as is, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this by having an list of the indices. When i went to remove one, i would remove the corresponding index from the index list. Then when i went to retrieve an element, i would first go to the index array, go the index that the user wanted, look up the new index, and use that to index into the unmodified list.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to pretend the item is not there, but you still want it to be backed by the DB. Well, it might be possible, but it will either be ineffective or you'll have to come up with some tricky algorithm.

The only thing that came to my mind right now is a `SortedMap<Integer, Integer>` that maps an `index` to `how many rows you have to skip`. E.g., you delete row 5, so you add (5,1). If you delete the row that is now considered 5, you change it to (5,2). If you delete row 3, you have to add (3,1) and change the other to (5,3). Then you delete row 8 and you add (8,4) ...

Or you could keep a sorted map of how many deletions you performed on particular indices, e.g., you'd have (3,1), (5,2) and (8,4) in previously mentioned example, but you'd have to iterate over all those numbers in every `get`, rather than just looking into the map for the closest previous index and have the number readily-available.